# Fill in blanks between flags in a sas dataset

Tags: sas

```
Id flag
1  -1
1  .
1 .
1 .
1 .
1  1
2. -1
2 .
2  1
2 .
```

I was looking for someting that assigns a value(lets say 0) between -1 and 1 if the id is identical for -1 and 1..or was trying to slice out data from the point -1 to 1 for a particular objectid

Output

```
Id  flag
1  -1
1 0
1 0
1 0
1 0
1 1
2  -1
2 0
2 1
2 .
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you post what output you want? What did you try?

Comment: Updated the question with the desired output

Comment: So do you stop setting missing to zero after the first record for the group with one? What about missing values that appear before the minus one value?

Comment: I want 0 just between -1 and 1... anything above or below -1 and 1 should still be missing for a particular objectid.

Comment: Im trying to slice out a piece of information between -1 and 1 for a particular id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to input values between -1 and 1 then you should try to retain a new variable that you then assign a value if the previous value was -1 and stop assigning it a value if the current value is 1. If you want these in the same variable you then write them over to a new variable depending on their value.

First we make some sample data.

```
data test;
    infile datalines;
    input id $1. flag best8.;
datalines;
1 -1
1
1 
1 
1 
1 1
2 -1
2 
2 1
2 
;
run;
```

And then the code.

```
data result (rename=(new_flag = flag));
    set test;
    if _n_ = 1 then
        cont_flag = .;

    prev_flag = lag(flag);

    if prev_flag = -1 then
        cont_flag = 0;
    if flag = 1 then
        cont_flag = .;

    if cont_flag = 0 then
        new_flag = 0;
    else if flag = -1 or flag = 1 then
        new_flag = flag;

    retain cont_flag;
    drop flag prev_flag cont_flag;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks Seba..this is super helpful!! It worked just the way i wanted!!